# MATLAB does not recognise Python environment. Mac M1

Tags: python, matlab, path, apple-m1, pyenv

I am trying to use `pyrunfile` to run a Python file that is in my current directory. However, MATLAB does not recognise the python environment that is present on my system. Here is my MATLAB command-window output:

```
>> pyrunfile("LSTM.py") 
Error using feval 
Python commands require a supported version of CPython. 

Related documentation
```

When trying to find my python environment, the following appears:

```
>> pyenv 
ans = 
PythonEnvironment with properties: 
Version: "" 
Executable: "" 
Library: "" 
Home: "" 
Status: NotLoaded 
ExecutionMode: InProcess
```

For reference the system is Mac OS Sonoma 14.1.1, and MATLAB is version R2022b.

Troubleshooting notes:

- Using `>> py` in the MATLAB command window yields and empty return.
- Using `>> python` in the MATLAB command window yields "Unrecognized function or variable 'python'." This would lead me to believe that Python is not in my PATH. However,
- using `python` in a terminal window starts the Python interpreter. So I suppose Python is in my PATH.

What else should I try?

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the manual? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-supported-python-implementation.html

Comment: Thanks Cris, its fixed. Downloaded the “aarch64” version of Java 8 as mentioned in this post https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1977529-how-to-use-python-from-matlab-on-mac-with-apple-silicon . Then redownloaded the newest version of MATLAB and it worked.